# simplemodal close iframe form after submit?

Tags: iframe, simplemodal

Simplemodal works perfectly but I dont know how to automatically close the Iframe after the form is submitted.
I have tried to get the event outside the modal options using js, but
if I close the modal window on the submit event, then the form is not submitted...

I have also added the class simplemodal-close to the input button, but it doest work in the form??

Any suggestions??
Here is my code

//Modal Window

```
modal.click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.modal('<iframe src="' + this.href + '" height="480" width="525" style="border:0" >',{
        containerCss:{
        backgroundColor:"#fff"
    },
    overlayClose:true,
    onShow: function (dialog) {
    $("input",dialog.data).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Here'); //Doesnt execute
        $.modal.close();
    parent.$.modal.close();
    alert('Here');
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just did it.. I didnt use iframe because after parent.$.modal.close().. The js included in that iframe didnt execute anymore..

So I just did it this way..

```
 //Modal Window
modal.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get(this.href,function(data){

        var resp = $('<div></div>').append(data); // wrap response
        $(resp).modal({
            overlayClose:true,
            minHeight:450,
            minWidth: 500,
            containerCss:{
                backgroundColor:"#fff",
                borderColor:"#fff"
                },
            onShow: function(dialog){
                autocomplete();
            }
        });
    });

 });
```

If I use a div instead that an iframe,, when I submit, the modal closes otherwise it stays open....

It was easy, but I got confused..